# Nginx/Passenger/Rails "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I made a small change to my Rails 4 application where I set response.headers in a before_action on ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_response_headers

  def set_response_headers
    response.headers['FOO'] = some_object.id if some_object
    response.headers['ABC'] = other_object.id if other_object
  end
end
```

Nginx error logs say:

```
2015/01/20 09:49:34 [error] 3401#0: *504273 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/v1/foos HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3380/generation-0/request:", host: "foo.com"
```

When I make the request to `/api/v1/foos`, I see the request hitting Rails and logs seem to progress as normal, but the response craps out.

I don't see many resolved issues on here or around Google with this specific issue, and I'm also not sure that this isn't a PEBCAK issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
response.headers['FOO'] = some_object.id.to_s if some_object
response.headers['ABC'] = other_object.id.to_s if other_object
```

Passenger require header value to be string or array